# Value at Risk with non-zero mean (RiskMetrics etc.)

Tags: quantiles, finance

RiskMetrics assumes zero mean for the calculation of value at risk (https://www.msci.com/documents/10199/5915b101-4206-4ba0-aee2-3449d5c7e95a)

In our data, the mean return is quite negative. Is there an alternative approach we can use to calculate VaR? The negative returns are due to the crisis period, while there is a reverse in the trend lately with returns being positive. Is there a way to include this new trend in our calculations in order to get a better result from the one that classic VaR would get?

Comment: The [tag:var] tag is for Vector AutoRegression, not Value at Risk. Since VaR is just a quantile of a distribution, I have added the [tag:quantiles] tag.

Answer (score 1):

Zero mean simplifies the general VaR approach, it's not an essential part of it.

If the mean is zero then the return variance expression simplifies to $\sigma^2_r=E[r^2]$. If the mean is not zero, then calculate the variance the usual way $\sigma^2_r=E[(r-\bar r)^2]$, then apply to the mean to get your VaR: $\bar r-\gamma \hat\sigma_r$.

Moreover, in a general formulation $(1-\alpha)$ VaR is simply a quantile of loss distribution: $v=F^{-1}(1-\alpha)$. Note, there's no mean or variance involved at all. It is when you use ellipticals, such as Gaussian, you get simpler expressions with variance, or means. In a general case you build the CDF of loss distribution, and get its quantile (percentile)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the mean is not necessarily zero in Riskmetrics. It depends on your definition of the mean equation. You should have a look in [Bawens (2006)][1] at page 83.

Comment: https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1002/jae.842

Comment: Can you summarise the contents of the link so the answer stays useful if the link rots?

Comment: $H_t=\lambda H_{t-1}+(1-\lambda)\epsilon_{t-1}'\epsilon_{t-1}$

 with $\epsilon_{t-1}$ denoting the vectors of at least two returns' errors.